# Minor nag with MathJax freezing computer

Tags: bug, mathjax

So, if I turn on my computer and open Firefox and go to Math Stackexchange's website, my Firefox freezes for 10 seconds.  In fact, today, I clicked on the link to Math Stackexchange, and immediately minimized my browser and tried to open up a PDF.  But, I couldn't do that either.  So, my computer is basically completely useless for 10 seconds.

Compared to all the benefits of MathJax, I agree this is a minor thing.  *But*, no computer program should act this way.  Can't something be done so that while it is getting started, or doing whatever it is doing, I can still run my computer?  I can't think of any other program I use that freezes my entire computer for 10 seconds, or even close to it.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, perhaps some firefox plugin clashes with the site. Have you tried starting FF [in safe-mode](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) and opening the site?

Comment: Which version of Firefox on what operating system? What extensions have you installed? Does the problem happen if you run Firefox with a [fresh profile](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)?

Comment: Possibly related: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/P2YOan5UVFo/eBfYCUybbNoJ If that is the case it _may_ help to install [STIX fonts](http://www.mathjax.org/help/fonts/).

Comment: @WillieWong Every version of Firefox I have used for months, and they change the version every few weeks, so several versions.  As far as OS, it's Windows 7.

Comment: It is possibly a Windows 7 problem. A similar problem was also reported with Chrome https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-bugs/sp36-I2kTtg/dysQePAF2yUJ

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3868/19341 and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5056/19341

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Firefox on Windows 7 and Windows Vista. Only for me it freezed up to 40 seconds.

I could fix it by deactivating hardware acceleration of the browser (which is activated by default in FF). In Firefox, go to Options => Advanced and uncheck the hardware acceleration box.